# Is there a way to return 404 Not Found for prohibited directory listings in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My web server is Apache. I have disabled directory listings via an `Options -Indexes` directive in a `.htaccess` file, so if a user navigates to a directory without an `index.html` file, he'll get a 403 Forbidden error. However, I'd like to return 404 Not Found in such instances instead. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/your/error/file/or/script
```

to override 403 with your own script, and make it return 404. for example, in PHP:

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/prohibited/directory/$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mod_rewrite for it:

```
RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule
my_hidden_dir.* not_found.php
```